# Save data to cookie

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, cookies

I want to save temporary data (id and name) from product page to cart via Ajax. The problem is to record new variables in cookie, using outstanding from Joomla file.
I tried:

```
$inputCookie  = JFactory::getApplication()->input->cookie;
$value        = $inputCookie->get($name = 'myCookie', $defaultValue = null);
$cookieExists = ($value !== null);
$inputCookie->set($name = 'myCookie', $value = '123', $expire = 0);
```

but in var_dump($_COOKIE) there is no 'myCoolie' variable with value.

And maybe for safety I need to use Session instead Cookie to keep products in cart?

Answer (score 6):

The problem being your code will never work the first time cause your trying to **set** a cookie value based on the **get** value, which is always `null` as you're never setting the initial value.

To set a cookie, you can use the following:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();

// Get the cookie
$value = $app->input->cookie->get('myCookie', null);

// If there's no cookie value, manually set it
if ($value == null)
{
    $value = HOWEVER YOU GET THE CART DATA
}

// Set the cookie
$time = time() + 604800; // 1 week
$app->input->cookie->set('myCookie', $value, $time, $app->get('cookie_path', '/'), $app->get('cookie_domain'), $app->isSSLConnection());
```

Answer (score 1):

This can help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206662/how-to-use-cookies-from-a-component

use setvar and getString methods

```
JRequest::setVar($var, $value, 'cookie');
JRequest::getString($var, $default, 'cookie')
```

Or

https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.Input.Cookie.html

Or

http://blog.tormix.com/joomla/set-and-get-cookies-in-joomla-cms/

Comment: JRequest class is deprecated for few years and will be removed in J!4